# Is there a way to click a cell in a DataGridView to expand it with another DataTable?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my Windows Form Application, I am using a DataGridView to display some DataTables I have, in these tables I have some regional information, I am trying to make it so that you can click on these region values in the DataGridViews cell and it will then expand and show all the yearly values I have of that region. For example, if a user clicked on the Cell in the grid that said "UK" it will then expand a table in the same datagridview that shows all the information I have on the UK etc.

Thank you

Comment: Hook the [CellClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick?view=netframework-4.7.2) event?

Comment: But is it then possible to expand some rows from another table after clicking it?

Comment: Try master and detail DataGridView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-create-master-detail-lists-with-the-windows-forms-datagrid-control